# Scraping thousands of URLs getting "Please specify how to connect" in power query

Tags: web-scraping, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

Here is my function code. I have another table with all my URLs. But when I try to plug my URLs into `CarData` it returns `Please specify how to connect` and shows me this window. Something I would like to not have to do manually for thousands of URLs. Why is it asking for this and how do I automate it for my thousands of URLs?

[image]

```
(CarData as text)=>
let
    Source = Web.BrowserContents(CarData),
    #"Extracted Table From Html" = Html.Table(Source, {{"Column1", ".key"}, {"Column2", ".value"}}, [RowSelector=".key"]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Extracted Table From Html",{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Changed Type"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Promoted Headers", "Gas Mileage", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("/", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Gas Mileage.1", "Gas Mileage.2"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Gas Mileage.1", type text}, {"Gas Mileage.2", type text}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type2","Transmission:","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Transmission"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Replaced Value", "SAE Net Torque @ RPM", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("@", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"SAE Net Torque @ RPM.1", "SAE Net Torque @ RPM.2"}),
    #"Changed Type3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"SAE Net Torque @ RPM.1", Int64.Type}, {"SAE Net Torque @ RPM.2", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type3",{{"SAE Net Torque @ RPM.1", "SAE Net Torque"}, {"SAE Net Torque @ RPM.2", "SAE Torque RPM"}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter2" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "SAE Net Horsepower @ RPM", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("@", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"SAE Net Horsepower @ RPM.1", "SAE Net Horsepower @ RPM.2"}),
    #"Changed Type4" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter2",{{"SAE Net Horsepower @ RPM.1", Int64.Type}, {"SAE Net Horsepower @ RPM.2", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type4",{{"SAE Net Horsepower @ RPM.1", "SAE Net Horsepower"}, {"SAE Net Horsepower @ RPM.2", "SAE Net Horsepower RPM"}, {"Displacement", "Displacement (L)"}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter3" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Renamed Columns1", "Displacement (L)", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("/", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Displacement (L).1", "Displacement (L).2"}),
    #"Changed Type5" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter3",{{"Displacement (L).1", type text}, {"Displacement (L).2", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Renamed Columns2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type5",{{"Displacement (L).2", "Displacement"}}),
    #"Changed Type6" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns2",{{"Displacement", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type6","L","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Displacement (L).1"}),
    #"Changed Type7" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced Value1",{{"Displacement (L).1", type number}}),
    #"Renamed Columns3" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type7",{{"Gas Mileage.1", "mpg city"}, {"Gas Mileage.2", "mpg Hwy"}}),
    #"Replaced Value2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Renamed Columns3","mpg Hwy","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"mpg Hwy"}),
    #"Replaced Value3" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value2","mpg City","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"mpg city"}),
    #"Changed Type8" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced Value3",{{"mpg city", Int64.Type}, {"mpg Hwy", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type8"
```

Here is the code for my URLs if you need it;

```
let
  Source = Binary.Decompress(File.Contents("path\trims.xml.gz"), Compression.GZip),
    #"Imported CSV" = Xml.Document(Source),
    Value = #"Imported CSV"{0}[Value],
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Value,{"Attributes"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Value"}),
    #"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Value", {"Name", "Namespace", "Value", "Attributes"}, {"Name", "Namespace", "Value.1", "Attributes"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Expanded Value",{"Value.1"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Other Columns1",{{"Value.1", "URLs"}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"URLs", type text}}),
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Data", each #"Table 3"([URLs]))
in
    #"Invoked Custom Function"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution it is not exact but it is a similar error;

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Dataflow-to-SAP-HANA-unable-to-connect-quot-Please-specify-how/td-p/605948